# Hibernate @Filter entity by @ManyToOne field

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, field, many-to-one

I'm trying to use Java's Hibernate @Filter on a many to one relationship field, but when I enable the filter and try to call a getAll method using the StockDailyRecord Service from an AJAX I get this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

This is my entity where I define the filter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_daily_record", catalog = "mkyong")
@FilterDef(name="stockDailyRecordFilter")
@Filters({
    @Filter(name="stockDailyRecordFilter", condition="stock.name = 'My stock'"),
})
public class StockDailyRecord extends Entity implements Serializable {
         ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false )
    public Stock getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }
}
```

However when I change the filter with the actual column in the database "stock_id" and compare it with the id I want the filter works without any exceptions.

```
@Filter(name="stockDailyRecordFilter", condition="stock_id = 10")
```

Here is how I enable the filter in the StockDailyRecordService:

```
    Session hSession = getSession();
    if (isAnonymous) {
        hSession.enableFilter("stockDailyRecordFilter");
    } else {
        hSession.disableFilter("stockDailyRecordFilter");
    }
```

Also, when I try the filter on other properties (say the StockDailyRecord has field "description") it works just fine. Is there a way to access the "name" property of the Stock entity from the Filter condition, because I don't really want to do the approach with the "stock_id = 10"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `stock` from filter definition

```
@Filter(name="stockDailyRecordFilter", condition="name = 'My stock'")
```

UPDATE 
So stock here is related table not the main table. You can try to join to subselect with IN

```
condition="stock_id in (select id from stock where name = 'My stock')"
```

Comment: After trying this I get: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column stock_daily_records0_.name does not exist".

Comment: Hibernate here sees "name" as a "stock_daily_records" column, but it is actually a "stock" table column

Comment: Updated answer with another approach

Comment: Thank you, that was a big help!

Comment: I can't understand though, why didn't Hibernate allow to use the "stock.name" method like you could in a NamedQuery for example?

Comment: Because in fact the condition is SQL and DB does not know about hibernate entity stock.